# Get a users email with Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am successfully logging in users with the JS Facebook SDK and I am able to retrieve the name if the user. However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the users email. I have tried adding `{scope:'email'}` in 3 different places, and I tried putting email in the field of the api call, `FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}...`

My project is in angular. I login the user when they click on the facebook login button. Below is the code I have. All of this code is in my `ngOnInit` function

```
window['fbAsyncInit'] = () => {
  FB.init({
    appId            : '...',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : false,
    version          : 'v2.12'
  }, {scope:'email'}); //scope for FB.init


  console.log('fb',FB);

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', (response) => {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log(response.authResponse);
      FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, {scope:'email'}); //scope for FB.api

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      console.log(response.status);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }, {scope:'email'}); //scope for FB.Event
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Here is my html for the button

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" 
  data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>
```

Comment: there is no scope parameter in the FB.init function. show your code of the login button, that is where it belongs.

Comment: I have a scope for FB.init all the way at the top. Its on the 7th line down. I put a comment next to it. I also pasted the html for the button at the bottom

Comment: you misunderstood, the scope parameter is pointless in FB.init, and it is pointless in the event.subscribe function. it is also pointless for the FB.api function. you can remove ALL your scope parameters, because they are all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one correct place for the scope parameter:

```
<div
  class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" 
  data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"
  data-scope="email"
>
</div>
```